# Compiling programmes in Visual Studio: Makefile or MSBuild? What are the differences?

Tags: visual-studio, makefile, msbuild

I am a beginner in development on an IDE like Visual Studio. To be specific, I have just installed Visual Studio for C development. Prior, I compiled my C code using a Makefile and GCC as my build system. However, Visual Studio, by default configures MSBuild for use as my build system.

Whilst investigating on the matter, I discovered Visual Studio's NMake, which I could utilise to call the `make` command to run a Makefile and compile my code that way.

Basically, I want to know what is the better way of compiling code in Visual Studio—whether to run a Makefile using NMake or to use the default that is MSBuild. I want details on the specific differences of these two methods, and perhaps the repercussions of using one over the other. Online resources don't provide frank answers on this question. Thus, I've turned to Stack Overflow for assistance.

***P.S.** After some research, I found someone mention that Visual Studio code maps don't work with NMake; however, I couldn't find any official statement to back that up. That was all I could find on the matter of this question.*

Comment: NMake is very primitive when compared with GNU make or even BSD make; Visual Studio comes with cmake that can generate makefiles if that is what you need as well as others that ae IMHO faster

Comment: Note that CMake is not `make` but will generate another build system's files including `make` and `msbuild`.

Comment: Your question is asking for an opinion but the 'correct' answer depends heavily on your own preferences. But I will say that if you plan for your current project to primarily work in Visual Studio (or VSCode), and you are using the Microsoft C/C++ compiler, and you want to focus on the code and not the build system, then let the IDE use MSBuild.

Comment: @60G7lMh I suggest you use MSBuild, you could take a look at my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild is the native build system for all projects in Visual Studio, including C and C++ projects. When you build a project in the Visual Studio integrated development environment (IDE), it invokes the `msbuild.exe` tool, which in turn consumes the `.vcxproj` project file, and various `.targets` and `.props` files. MSBuild allows you to easily target all the Windows platforms that Visual Studio supports from a single codebase.

**[NMake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=msvc-160)** is a command-line tool included with Visual Studio, which builds projects based on commands contained in a description file, usually a makefile. NMake must run in a Developer Command Prompt window which has the environment variables set for the tools, libraries, and include file paths required to build at the command line. NMake was historically used before the advent of managed code when the dependencies between components were simpler.

For NMake why not work with VS code map, I didn't find a command of it to generate a vcxproj file. But [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-maps-for-cpp?view=vs-2022) show the structure is relied on the vcxproj. So I think this is the reason why VS Code Map not support NMake.

I suggest you use msbuild. msbuild can be used directly on vxproj files, and compiling through GUI is more convenient than writing scripts.

Comment: By the looks of the page you linked to, it seems that the structure is reliant more on Visual C++ rather than MSBuild, the build system which invokes Visual C++. (Not that I know whether Visual C++ needs a .vcxproj file) So, I think it is still possible to use a Makefile instead, by running the Visual C++ compiler and linker.

Anyway, I've decided to stick with MSBuild because Makefiles have their own problems, and I don't want to cause even more problems by avoiding MSBuild. Maybe in the future I'll create my own custom build system.